# Regex Lookaheads

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to capture content of root `<pubDate>` element, but in document it can be either within `<item>` element or within `<channel>` element. Also `<item>` is child of `<channel>` I'll bring example

```
<channel>
  ...
  <pubDate>10/2/2010</pubDate>
  ...
  <item>
    ...
    <pubDate>13/2/2029</pubDate>
    ...
  </item>
  ...
</channel>
```

need to capture **10/2/2010**

With the `<item>` no problem, can capture it, along with its `<pubDate>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know JavaScript, so I can't help you with the DOM. I agree 100% that it's a bad idea to try and parse XML with regex. There might be a quick, very dirty, and very brittle workaround, though:

If indentation is consistent throughout the file, and `<channel>` elements are always at the same level of indentation, you could use that fact as a guide for the regex. In your example `/^ {2}<pubDate>([^<]*)<\/pubdate>/m` (= two spaces after start-of-line) might just work.

Use this at your own risk. Here be dragons etc.

Answer (score 2):

Regexp is not a good tool to deal with programming language that are parsed with context-free grammars. Try to use XML DOM to do the job.

Comment: any hint or example on how to do with XML DOM? I don't want to be bound to Microsoft.XMLDOM indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQuery and see if this helps reading/parsing the XML: http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/

KM